# Am I subject to the 2 year rule?

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

My DS2019 states that I am not subject to the two-year residence requirement, however my visa in my passport states that I am subject to the 212(e) two-year rule.

Comment: From a quick search, it sounds like the DS-2019 is issued first and the actual J1 visa second? I'd guess then that the visa is correct, not the DS-2019. I suggest you ask the embassy or consulate where you were interviewed for clarification though. Is the residence requirement a problem - do you need it changing?

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer it not applied. But i think you are right, visa must be final decision.

Comment: It may have been a clerical error copying the details over to the visa rather than a deliberate decision. It won't hurt to ask about it anyway if you can.

Comment: Can whoever down voted this question leave a comment to explain why?

Comment: Is this question about a long stay or about (a series of) short visits? If about a long stay I can move this question to expatriates.

Comment: Neither the DS-2019 nor visa is necessarily correct. If in doubt, you might want to ask for an [advisory opinion](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/advisory-opinions.html) from the Department of State waiver review division.

Comment: @MJeffryes A 2-year requirement from 212(e) is related to a long-term visa so the question probably belongs on [Expatriates.se] except it's unanswerable in its current form. (I didn't downvote it)

Comment: @mkennedy If that's the reason then they should have said so! Down votes without explanation are very unfriendly in my opinion.

Comment: @MJeffryes Oh, I agree.